# How to change color of Button (material-ui) on navigation on it?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

There is react + material-ui application and used Button component.

```
<Button classes={{root: classes.button, label: classes.label}} variant="raised" color="primary">
```

Which attribute do I need change for changing background color of button on click?
By default it is yellow.

I got Button component from here https://material-ui-next.com/demos/buttons/

Comment: This should help you https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Define a `secondary` color in the material-ui theme like:

const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: lightBlue,
    secondary: pink,
  },
})

2. Define a state variable holding the value of the color property, set it to 'primary' by default.
3. Add a method to your component to handle changing the value of the `color` variable:

   handleClick(e){
   this.setState({
      color: 'secondary'
   })
   }
4. Add `onClick` attribute to the button like

onClick={(event) => this.onClick(event)}